# dart fix, giving different results based on the machine it is run on

Tags: flutter, dart

I am seeing a behavior I struggle to understand right now, regarding `dart fix`.

On my machine, I have a script doing a bunch of dart code generation inside one of my package's folder. After the code is being generated, if I run the `dart fix --dry-run` command this is what I get:

```
Computing fixes in design_system (dry run)...


16 proposed fixes in 2 files.


lib/src/constants/file1.dart

  prefer_const_constructors - 4 fixes
  unused_import - 1 fix


lib/src/constants/file2.dart
  prefer_const_constructors - 10 fixes
  unused_import - 1 fix
```

and this is my environment:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at /Users/adrien.padol/fvm/versions/stable
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (3 months ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2
```

Now, this same script, is run (on the same version of the sources) on a Github hosted agent, and this is what I get:

```
Computing fixes in design_system (dry run)...


4 proposed fixes in 4 files.

lib/src/widgets/data_display/file1.dart
  type_init_formals - 1 fix

lib/src/widgets/data_entry/file2.dart
  unnecessary_lambdas - 1 fix

lib/src/widgets/feedback/file3.dart
  type_init_formals - 1 fix

lib/src/widgets/navigation_components/file4.dart
  type_init_formals - 1 fix
```

Yet the environment seems to be the same (outside of the agent being a linux machine):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 5.15.0-1014-azure, locale C.UTF-8)

    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/stable-3.0.1-x64

    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (3 months ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700

    • Engine revision caaafc5604

    • Dart version 2.17.1

    • DevTools version 2.12.2
```

So, for the same script, and the same source code, I manage to get two completely different outputs of the `dart fix` command, and I don't really understand why this is happenning ...

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: Do both environments have identical `analysis_options.yaml` files?  Is the `analysis_options.yaml` file dependent on any packages?  If so, are both environments using the same versions of those packages?

Comment: Yes the files are the same, because it is checked in our repository, and they both scripts run target the same version of the sources.
But I'll have to check for the dependencies